# Make agrep output offset of the match

Tags: string, grep, string-matching, agrep

I'm trying to use agrep and I can do approximate matches but I need to know where the match starts and where it finishes. Are there any flags that would allow me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Is `--show-position` what you're looking for? From [the docs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/agrep):

> **Output control:**
>
> > **--show-position**
> >
> > > Prefix each output record with the start and end offset of the first match within the record. The offset of the first character of the record is 0. The end position is given as the offset of the first character after the match.